# How to bind the values of dynamically generated controls in WPF using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working with a MVVM appliaction in which I generate controls dinamically using a list with values taken from a database. The problem is that I don't know how to pass the values of the controls to the view model when the controls are generated dinamically.
I have created a class with the values that I want to pass to the view model like this:

```
class Bindeo {
 int id;
 string especifique;
 bool padece;

 public Bindeo(int id, string especifique, bool padece) {
  id = this.id;
  especifique = this.especifique;
  padece = this.padece;
 }
}
```

And i'm generating the values dinamically like this:

```
 for (int x = 0; x < Math.Floor(cantidadElementosPorColumna) + residuo; x++) {
  CAT_GINECOBSTETRICOS enfermedad = vm.EnfermedadesGinecobstetricas[x];
  Grid grid = new Grid();
  grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
  grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

  Label tituloEnfermedad = new Label {
   Content = enfermedad.DESCRIPCION
  };
  Grid.SetColumn(tituloEnfermedad, 0);
  grid.Children.Add(tituloEnfermedad);

  Grid radios = new Grid();
  radios.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
  radios.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
  RadioButton si = new RadioButton {
   Content = "Si"
  };


  RadioButton no = new RadioButton {
   Content = "No"
  };
  Grid.SetColumn(si, 0);
  Grid.SetColumn(no, 1);
  radios.Children.Add(si);
  radios.Children.Add(no);
  Grid.SetColumn(radios, 1);
  grid.Children.Add(radios);

  TextBox tb = new TextBox();

  si.Command = vm.GenerarReporteCommand;
  si.CommandParameter = new Bindeo((int) enfermedad.ID_CAT_GINECOBSTETRICOS, tb.Text, si.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault());

  EspecifiqueGinecobstetricos1.Children.Add(tb);

  GinecobstetricosColumna1.Children.Add(grid);
 }
```

What I'm doing here is that I want to bind to the `si` RadioButton a command in the view model, and send as parameter to the command the object `Bindeo` when a radio button is clicked. The values that I take for create the object Bindeo is the id of the object of the database that i'm referencing, the value of the textbox and the value of the `si`radio button, but when I click the radio button and the command is triggered, the object sended to the command is not taking the actulized values, instead is taken the values when the controls are created. How can I update the values to send them to the view model and not sending nulls?

Comment: Taken literally, the answer to your question is "you don't". Creating controls in code-behind is mutually exclusive with MVVM. If you want to do the former, you need to create the bindings in code-behind as well. See first marked duplicate. If you want to do the latter, you need to use data templates and let the framework create the controls for you instead of doing it yourself in code-behind. If you do it that way, then you declare the bindings in XAML just like with any other controls. See other marked duplicates (and the other thousand or so other identical questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not MVVM. In MVVM you never create controls directly, you instead assign data to properties and then write your XAML to respond to those changes. If at any point you need to call methods on GUI elements then you have a number of options e.g. behaviours.

In your specific case, you're trying to display a list of items, in which case you should start by using an ItemsControl. You then declare [Data Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) in your XAML to specify how that data should be displayed, and you set the Panel Template to something other than the default StackPanel. Generally speaking, Grid isn't the best panel type to use for this, due to the need to also specify the row definitions, but [there are certainly ways around that](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html).

Here's [a good tutorial](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) to help get you started with all this, note the section titled "ItemsControl with data binding".